# Why can't I seem to import the OBJLoader module for Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been stumped for a few days on this issue. I cannot seem to import OBJLoader for Three.js. This is obviously important because I want custom 3D models in my game.

---

I have two error messages:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three-obj-loader". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".**

and

> **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

---

```
import {OBJLoader} from 'three-obj-loader'

// load a resource
loader.load(

    // resource URL
    '/Users/dmitri/Desktop/flame/models/fresh_fire_01 (1).obj',
    // called when resource is loaded
    function ( object ) {

        scene.add( object );
    },

    // called when loading is in progresses
    function ( xhr ) {

        console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
    },

    // called when loading has errors
    function ( error ) {

        console.log( 'An error happened' );
    }
);

// const loader = new OBJLoader()
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff)

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// loader.load("/Users/dmitri/Desktop/flame/models/fresh_fire_01
(1).obj",
function(object){
    //     scene.add(object)
    // })

    var run = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(run);
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}
run()
```

And here is my HTML code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js">.
    </script>

    <script src="/script.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my *app.js* source code:

```
const express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 8080)

app.use(express.static("public"))

app.listen(app.get("port"), function() {
    return
})
```

Here's my file structure:

---

models

--fresh-fire-01 (1).obj

public

--index.html

--script.js

app.py

---

I have tried every solution that I can possibly think of. I put the source for OBJLoader in my directory. I required it. I even put the OBJLoader source code inside of my *script.js* source code. Nothing seemed to work.

Comment: follow [this](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/OBJLoader) and add the other callbacks into the `load()` method. The error callback might give you more clue as to why its not working

Comment: it still returns two errors
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three-obj-loader". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: There, I just updated the post so that you can see my problem. the problem that you mentioned wasn't actually the problem I was dealing with and could've been easily avoided by just looking at the docs. But I genuinely have no idea what I've done and I can't find it on any documents anywhere

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: I am not usign webpack

Comment: Because you are not transpiling your code (webpack or rollup), your line `import {OBJLoader} from 'three-obj-loader'` is being read directly in the browser, but the browser can not load from the path 'three-obj-loader'. Without transpiling, it would need to be a full url (or relative url).

Comment: Documentation is [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation). You are running three.js via  CDN/static, but trying to load OBJLoader is if you are using an npm build tool.

Answer (score 6):

Three.js has its own OBJLoader. It is better to use native loaders instead of third parties.
If you look at 'three-obj-loader' you can see it's outdated. 4 years ago last update.
So, try to import OBJLoader from three.js library

Change:

```
import {OBJLoader} from 'three-obj-loader'
```

to:

```
import {OBJLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ A 'good answer' also includes a sentence or two in plain text that explains why you think your solution will work. You should edit your answer to cover this.  Please visit SO Help Center and specifically this guideline for more details >>> stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @inputforcolor, Is it ok now?

Comment: I've upvoted your answer Valerian _ Welcome again ; )